# space between radiobutton and label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, apex

I want to add space between radio button and the label. I am using selectradio and bootstrap. I am not able to apply style to select option. Is there any way to do this?

```
<div class="form-group" id="notificationtypeGroup">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="SendcardOptions"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <div class="radio-inline2">
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!notifytype}" id="notifyInfo"  layout="lineDirection" onclick="shownotifyoption(this.value)" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!NotifyOptions}"></apex:selectoptions>
             </apex:selectRadio>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
.radio-inline2 { padding-left: 10px; }
```

to your custom CSS (or whatever padding value you need)